# Error Undefined index: al cargar un excel - laravel 5

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar con este error.

Estoy tratando de cargar un archivo en excel a una tabla en una bd, Pero me aparece ese error, y sinceramente ya le he dado mil vueltas y no se porque no me toma el dato.

Estoy tratando de ingresar estos valores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es mi funcion.

```
 public function importexceladmisiones(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->hasFile('import_file')){
            $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();

            $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();

            if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){

                foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $value) {
                    if(!empty($value)){
                        foreach ($value as $v) {        
                            $insert[] = 
                            [
                                'tipo_documentoentidad' => $v['tipo_documentoentidad'],
                                'numerodocumentoentidad' => $v['numerodocumentoentidad'],
                                'tipodocumentocliente' => $v['tipodocumentocliente'],
                                'numerodocumentocleinte' => $v['numerodocumentocleinte'],
                                'primerapellido' => $v['primerapellido'],
                                'segundoapellido' => $v['segundoapellido'],
                                'primernombre' => $v['primernombre'],
                                'segundonombre' => $v['segundonombre'],
                                'Fechacita' => $v['Fechacita'],
                                'Horacita' => $v['Horacita'],
                                'tiposervicio' => $v['tiposervicio'],
                                'examen' => $v['examen'],
                                'enfasis' => $v['enfasis'],
                                'profesional' => $v['profesional'],
                                'fechaadmision' => $v['fechaadmision'],
                                'estadoproceso' => $v['estadoproceso']
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }


                if(!empty($insert)){
                    admisiones::insert($insert);
                    return back()->with('success','Insert Record successfully.');
                }

            }

        }

        return back()->with('error','Please Check your file, Something is wrong there.');
    }
```

Este es el error que me aparece

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así lo cargo desde mi vista.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="box" style="border:1px solid #d2d6de;" >

             <div class="box-header" style="background-color:#f5f5f5;border-bottom:1px solid #d2d6de;">
            <h3>Importar archivo:</h3>
            <form style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 20px;" action="{{ route('admin.ruta.import.excadmin') }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="file" name="import_file" />
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <br/>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Subir Archivo</button>
            </form>
            <br/>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Gracias por leer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error era porque estos campos Fechacita y Horacita estaban así en mayuscula en la base, y laravel lo pasa a minuscula, en el momento en el cambie esos valores en la base, se arreglo el problema.

-'Fechacita' => $v['Fechacita'],

-'Horacita' => $v['Horacita'],

Espero les sirva de algo :)